# Find indices of non zero and count the gaps between occurrences

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame `a` with some 0 and non-0 values. For example:

```
0,0,0,30,0,05,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,0
```

I tried to get the non-zero indices by using `which(a!=0)` and was able to get `4 6 12 15`. But my result should look something like this:

```
Col1 Col2
 0   -
 0   -
 0   -
 30  4
 0   -
 5   2
 0   -
 0   -
 0   -
 0   -
 0   -
 6   6
 0   -
 0   -
 7   3
 0   -
```

So what I need is the difference between successive occurrences as the second column. The value against 0 could be either blank or 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c(0,0,0,30,0,05,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,0)
```

Create a matching vector:

```
y <- rep(NA,length(x))
```

I filled the empty slots with `NA`; it's not really possible to use a "blank" placeholder in a numeric column. You could use `rep(0,length(x))` (or `numeric(length(x))` instead.

Find non-zero elements:

```
nzpos <- which(x!=0)
```

Fill the non-zero positions with the appropriate values:

```
y[nzpos] <- c(nzpos[1],diff(nzpos))
data.frame(x,y)
```

Comment: This code returns a wrong value if the first element is non-zero (it should set NA, or maybe zero). I had the same problem ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`rle`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rle.html) capability to count consecutive equal values :

```
DF <- data.frame(Col1=c(0,0,0,30,0,05,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,7,0),Col2=NA)

# count the length of groups of consecutive zeros
rleRes <- rle(DF$Col1==0)
# we add +1 since we include the next non-zero in the count
counts <- rleRes$lengths[rleRes$values] + 1
# if the last group of zero is not terminated by a non-zero, 
# we don't need to add the last count
if(tail(DF$Col1,1) == 0)
  counts <- counts[-length(counts)]
# if the first value is non-zero, then we need to set Count=0 (or NA) because 
# is not preceded by a group of zero
if(head(DF$Col1,1) != 0)
  counts <- c(0,counts)
# set the count on the second Column
DF$Col2[DF$Col1!=0] <- counts

> DF
   Col1 Col2
1     0   NA
2     0   NA
3     0   NA
4    30    4
5     0   NA
6     5    2
7     0   NA
8     0   NA
9     0   NA
10    0   NA
11    0   NA
12    6    6
13    0   NA
14    0   NA
15    7    3
16    0   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

To get your expected result you could simply subtract the values you got:

```
which(a!=0) - c(0, which(a!=0)[-4]) # 4 2 6 3
```

You can then create the new column with this values.

```
a$B <- 0
a$B[which(a!=0)] <- which(a!=0) - c(0, which(a!=0)[-4])
```

Output:

```
    A B
1   0 0
2   0 0
3   0 0
4  30 4
5   0 0
6   5 2
7   0 0
8   0 0
9   0 0
10  0 0
11  0 0
12  6 6
13  0 0
14  0 0
15  7 3
16  0 0
```

Comment: I thought that I will do this but then maybe I don't some function might be there for this. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This code returns a wrong value if the first element is non-zero (it should set NA, or maybe zero). I had the same problem ;)